# How to migrate maven plugins form maven to gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am migrating my spring boot project from maven to gradle. I have done dependencies migration, but have problems with plugin migration. Need an assistanse. Also if there any real example with comparing maven and gradle plugin will be appreciated. I have already done stuffs like gradle init and so I need something new. Here is my code:

```
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>/config/setting/setting.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>report-sonar</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-sonar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

2 plugins I am struggling with. If you could show me the migrations of this two, I think i will manage to do the others.

Answer (score 1):

For both of your plugins there is a gradle plugin,too.

The docs look pretty promising.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/pmd_plugin.html